# Can i store a Queue in viewstate? only will store the first item i add to queue

Tags: c#, asp.net

EDIT: ViewState does not change when browser is refreshed, so even if you write to viewstate it will not save the data. DOH!

Hey, as the question states i am trying to store a Queue in a viewstate (to track postbacks and refreshes to stop a form from resubmitting).

The Queue is only saving with a count of 1 (the first item that is added to it) no matter how many items i add.

Here is just the viewstate code:

```
    // New Queue of strings
private Queue<string> sTemp;

 private Queue<string> p_tempQue
{
    set
    {
        ViewState["sTemp"] = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return (Queue<string>)ViewState["sTemp"];
    }
}

//BasePage constructor 
public BasePage()
 {
        //create a Queue of string
        //sTemp = new Queue<string>();
        this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
        this.Init += new EventHandler(this.Page_Init);

 }


//In the 'page_Init' event we have created a simple hidden field by name 'hdnGuid' which is attached to the page on the first hit itself. 
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //initializing the hidden field

    //create a hidden field with a ID
    HiddenField hdnGuid = new HiddenField();
    hdnGuid.ID = "hdnGuid";

    //if it is the first time the page is loaded, create a new guid and assign it as the hidden field value 
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        hdnGuid.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    //add the hidden field to the page
    Page.Form.Controls.Add(hdnGuid);
}

//In the 'page_Load' event we check if the hidden field value is same as the old value. In case the value is not same that means it's a 'postback'
//and if the value is same then its 'refresh'. As per situation we set the 'httpContent.Items["Refresh"]' value. 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(p_tempQue != null)
    sTemp = p_tempQue;
    else
        sTemp = new Queue<string>();

    //The hdnGuid will be set the first time page is loaded, else the hdnGuid 
    //will be set after each time the form is submitted using javascript.

    //assign the hidden field currently on the page for manipulation
    HiddenField h1 = (HiddenField)(Page.Form.FindControl("hdnGuid"));
    //create an instance of the GuidClass
    GuidClass currentGuid = new GuidClass();
    //set the GuidClass Guid property to the value of the hidden field
    currentGuid.Guid = h1.Value;


    //check to see if the Queue of strings contains the string which is the current Guid property of the GuidClass
    //if the are equal, then the page was refreshed
    if (sTemp.Contains<string>(currentGuid.Guid))
    {
        //adds item as key/value pair to share data between an System.Web.IHttpModule interface and an System.Web.IHttpHandler interface during an HTTP request.
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("IsRefresh", true);
    }
    //if they are not requal, the page is not refreshed
    else
    {
       //if the current Guid property in the GuidClass is not null or not an empty string
       //add the new Guid to the Queue
       if (!(currentGuid.Guid.Equals(null) || currentGuid.Guid.Equals("")))
          sTemp.Enqueue(currentGuid.Guid);

     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("IsRefresh", false);
    }

    p_tempQue = sTemp;
}
```

Comment: I think you would be better off persisting the queue data as an array.

Comment: So when you debug your code at the final line when you do  `p_tempQue = sTemp;` you see that sTemp has more than 1 entry in it and then on the next post back it only has 1 entry in it?

Comment: The problem was i was testing refresh, and on refresh viewstate variables are not updated. So sTemp will only increase in count on postbacks (clicking the submit button).  This method is not going to work for me. I have changed the code to use httpModule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i was testing refresh, and on refresh viewstate variables are not updated. So sTemp will only increase in count on postbacks (clicking the submit button). This method is not going to work for me. I have changed the code to use httpModule.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't directly addressing your question the standard way to eliminate duplicate form submissions with the refresh button is [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). You might still need to prevent double clicking the submit button though.

Comment: unfortunately that does not work well for me as the control is a .ascx control implemented in each .aspx page. I am also posting back to same page if user enters a invalid e-mail with an alert. I would really like to be able to stop this within the same page if possible. I will keep looking

Answer (score 0):

It will store the entire data structure in ViewState - which is both good and bad. If you are persisting a very large object, it will bloat your ViewState tremendously.

Comment: my problem is that the Queue is only saving with a count of 1, no matter how many items are added to the Queue...